# For which $r=r(p, q)$ does the inequality $a^p + a^q \ge a^r$ hold true? Here $a, p, q\in\mathbb{R}, a>0, p, q>1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}, a>0$ and assume $p, q>1$. My question is: there exists some $r=r(p, q)$ such that the inequality
$$a^p + a^q \ge a^r ?$$

I am in trouble with that since both the cases $0<a<1$ and $a\ge 1$ can occur and I don't know how to manage them simultaneously.

Could someone please help me with that? What are possible choices of $r$ which make the above inequality true?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<a<1$, $$r\ge\frac{\ln\left(a^p+a^q\right)}{\ln a}$$
For $a>1$, $$r\le\frac{\ln\left(a^p+a^q\right)}{\ln a}$$
Let $$f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(x^p+x^q\right)}{\ln x}$$
As $f'(x)<0$, and
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\min(p,q)\quad,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\max(p,q)$$
The $r$ has only to meet
$$\min(p,q)\le r\le\max(p,q)$$